# Изменение пунктов в разных разделах

Tags: javascript, jquery

При изменении `div.plans-item-title` должно происходить изменение в `select.plans-select` и отображаться нужный `div.number` (это сделал и работает). В какую сторону копать, что бы при изменении в `select` изменялись теперь уже`div`ы?

```js
$(".plans-item-title").click(function() {
  $(".plans-item-title").removeClass('active');
  $().addClass('active');

  $('.plans-items').removeClass('active');
  $($(this).attr('data-class')).addClass('active');

  $('#plans-select').val($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.plans-items-title {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.plans-item-title {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 15%;
  flex: 0 0 15%;
  max-width: 15%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #777;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.plans-item-title.active {
  color: #222;
  cursor: default;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
}

.plans-items-title-select {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 40px;
}

.plans-row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.plans-items {
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  display: none;
}

.plans-items.active {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.plans-item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.numder {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plans-row row">
  <div class="plans-items-title">
    <div class="plans-item-title active" data-class=".plan-room-1">1-к</div>
    <div class="plans-item-title" data-class=".plan-room-2">2-к</div>
    <div class="plans-item-title" data-class=".plan-room-3">3-к</div>
  </div>
  <select name="plans-select" id="plans-select" class="plans-items-title-select">
    <option value="1-к" data-class=".plan-room-1">1-к</option>
    <option value="2-к" data-class=".plan-room-2">2-к</option>
    <option value="3-к" data-class=".plan-room-3">3-к</option>
  </select>
  <div id="plan-room-1" class="plans-items plan-room-1 active">
    <div class="numder">1</div>
  </div>
  <div id="plan-room-2" class="plans-items plan-room-2">
    <div class="numder">2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="plan-room-3" class="plans-items plan-room-3">
    <div class="numder">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например:

```js
$(".plans-item-title").click(function() {
  
  var $this = $(this),
      classItem = $this.data('class'),
      plans = $('.plans-items');
  
  plans.filter('.plan-'+classItem)
  .add($this)
  .addClass('active')
  .siblings()
  .removeClass('active');

  $('#plans-select').val(classItem);
});

$('.plans-items-title-select').on('change', function() {
  var val = this.value,
      title = $('.plans-item-title'),
      plans = $('.plans-items');
  
  plans.filter('.plan-'+val)
  .addClass('active')
  .siblings()
  .removeClass('active');
  
  title.filter('.title-'+val)
  .addClass('active')
  .siblings()
  .removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.plans-items-title {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.plans-item-title {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 15%;
  flex: 0 0 15%;
  max-width: 15%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #777;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.plans-item-title.active {
  color: #222;
  cursor: default;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
}

.plans-items-title-select {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 40px;
}

.plans-row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.plans-items {
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  display: none;
}

.plans-items.active {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.plans-item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.numder {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

  
<div class="plans-row row">
  
  <div class="plans-items-title">
    <div class="plans-item-title title-room-1 active" data-class="room-1">1-к</div>
    <div class="plans-item-title title-room-2" data-class="room-2">2-к</div>
    <div class="plans-item-title title-room-3" data-class="room-3">3-к</div>
  </div>
  
  <select name="plans-select" id="plans-select" class="plans-items-title-select">
    <option value="room-1" >1-к</option>
    <option value="room-2" >2-к</option>
    <option value="room-3" >3-к</option>
  </select>
  
  <div id="plan-room-1" class="plans-items plan-room-1 active">
    <div class="numder">1</div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="plan-room-2" class="plans-items plan-room-2">
    <div class="numder">2</div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="plan-room-3" class="plans-items plan-room-3">
    <div class="numder">3</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".plans-item-title").click(function() {
  $(".plans-item-title").removeClass('active');
  $().addClass('active');

  $('.plans-items').removeClass('active');
  $($(this).attr('data-class')).addClass('active');

  $('#plans-select').val($(this).text());
});

$( "select" ).change(function() {
    var $selected = $("select#plans-select option:selected").data("class");
    $('.plans-items').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass($selected)) {
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        }
    })
})
```

```css
.plans-items-title {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

.plans-item-title {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 15%;
  flex: 0 0 15%;
  max-width: 15%;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0 10px;
  color: #777;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.plans-item-title.active {
  color: #222;
  cursor: default;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222;
}

.plans-items-title-select {
  margin-top: 50px;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 40px;
}

.plans-row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.plans-items {
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 45px;
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  display: none;
}

.plans-items.active {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.plans-item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.numder {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="plans-row row">
  <div class="plans-items-title">
    <div class="plans-item-title active" data-class=".plan-room-1">1-к</div>
    <div class="plans-item-title" data-class=".plan-room-2">2-к</div>
    <div class="plans-item-title" data-class=".plan-room-3">3-к</div>
  </div>
  <select name="plans-select" id="plans-select" class="plans-items-title-select">
    <option value="1-к" data-class="plan-room-1">1-к</option>
    <option value="2-к" data-class="plan-room-2">2-к</option>
    <option value="3-к" data-class="plan-room-3">3-к</option>
  </select>
  <div id="plan-room-1" class="plans-items plan-room-1 active">
    <div class="numder">1</div>
  </div>
  <div id="plan-room-2" class="plans-items plan-room-2">
    <div class="numder">2</div>
  </div>
  <div id="plan-room-3" class="plans-items plan-room-3">
    <div class="numder">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

У option убрал точку из значение data-class.